# Oracle Datamodeler generate DDL without database name

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I use Oracle datamodeler in order to design the database of an important application (240 tables).

I want (for clarity : My boss wants) generate DDL without database name.
Indeed, when I generate DDL (Ctrl + shift + E), the datamodeler prefix my table names by the database name. Here is an screenshoot of DDL generate :

[image]

I want to remove the part underlined.I don't find any option to remove it.

Comment: Unrelated but: your terminology is wrong. That is not a "database name" that is a "*schema* name". A schema and a database are two *very* different things in Oracle

Comment: Sorry for my inconsistent with Oracle principles.

Answer (score 0):

After generation use the "Find and replace" function to get rid of the database name. Use blank string to replace with.

Comment: From what I gathered, it is a good way, because you use this script only for demo purposes, you don't need to keep it up-to-date